# Is there a way to perform "linear regression" with an interval censored response variable in R?

Tags: regression, linear, interval-censoring

I am looking for a way to perform something like linear regression, but with an interval censored response variable (in R).

I want to know whether there is a (statistically significant) linear relationship between the continuous predictor variable X and the interval censored response variable Y (with Ylower and Yupper as interval boundaries) and whether this relationship depends on the categorical variable F (factor with two levels).

I am looking for something like

```
model = (cbind(Ylower,Yupper) ~ X * F, data = example_data)
Anova(model, type=3)
```

where there is also some way for model validation.
Finally my main interest is how much Y decreases for an increase of 1 unit in X (in dependence of F, of course).

Is there any way to do this in R?

I have looked into the survival package, but what I am looking for is not exactly survival analysis, as I am looking for the LINEAR relationship between the two variables.

Or: Is there any baseline distribution in survival analysis that could lead to the desired result?

Here is some example data:

```
structure(list(Ylower = c(2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 4, 9, 5, 6, 4, 15, 13, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3), Yupper = c(4, 7, 3, 10, 4, 8, 14, 9, 11, 9, 16, 16, 11, 10, 9, 8, 11, 10, 6, 6, 5, 3, 6), F = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 1.2, 2.5, 
2.8, 4.5, 4.7, 5.5, 6.2, 7, 9, 10.2)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am glad for any input!

Comment: Are you familiar with Tobit models? They might be what you're looking for. 
Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model
Some R function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-9/topics/tobit

Comment: Thanks! No, I am not (yet). After a first check it seems that tobit models assume a fixed upper/lower boundary for all observations (same for all). This results in left- or righ-censoring of the observations. But my data is interval-censored, for each single observation I only know the upper and the lower limit of the value that my response value Y could possibly have been for a given X. But what is interesting is that the tobit function from the AER package is implemented by using the survreg function from the survival package. Can I perform linear regression with survreg(..,dist="gaussian")?

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood what you meant with interval-censored. Sorry, I'm not familiar with survival models. But it looks to me that you are just dealing with a regression situation in which there is additional uncertainty regarding the exact value of the response. Can you formulate some kind of assumption for the distribution of responses within these intervals, then derive expected value and error per response, and weight the responses accordingly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you are asking about R code, your question is off-topic. But if you want to discuss methods for interval censored data, it is on-topic. Right now, it seems like sort of a a mix.

Comment: Hi, my main interest is to find a way to properly anylse the data.

Comment: I would have to assume a uniform distribution of the response within the interval, as I do not have any infomation on which I could place a better assumtion. But I am not sure whether I understand you comment correctly. Do you suggest I would for example assume a normal distribution and then take the mean and standard error and then perform actual linear regression with a weighted response?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no experience with this kind of data, and don't know if there are canonical ways to analyze them. I'm just brainstorming what I would do if I had not found a good solution after thorough research.
If you assume uniform distributions within the intervals, you could estimate y as (a+b)/2, and the error as ((b-a)^2)/12. Then weight the y's accordingly in a regression.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simulate a large number of datasets, in each of which you draw the y's from a uniform distribution in the respective interval. Then run the regression on each dataset, and derive the distribution of your estimates of interest (the beta weight of X) from the simulations.